# Openstack- unable to login from snapshot instance

Tags: migration, openstack, snapshot, openstack-nova

I took a snapshot from one instance in an openstack and put the snapshot as image in another openstack deployment, then tried to run it on a flavor that has greater hardware than required. Everything seems to go smooth but I'm unable to login into the new instance. Any suggestions?
where are the credentials stored in a snapshot?

1. -> I have two Openstack deployments, say op1 and op2.
2. -> I have an ubuntu 18.04 LTS instance snapshot in op1.
3. -> I downloaded the snapshot from op1.
4. -> I created an image of the snapshot in op2.
5. ->In op2 I made a flavor to accommodate the instance.
6. -> I booted it with the default network and security group.
7. -> Everything seemed to go fine.
8. -> Then the login screen appeared in the vnc console of the instance.
9. -> I entered the snapshot username and password.
10. -> It shows invalid/wrong username or password.

```
-
```

Now, I don't know where the credentials got lost. In my experience it should be stored inside the snapshot itself. Here is the guide I followed [enter link description here](https://docs.fuga.cloud/migrate-an-instance-from-one-openstack-to-another)

Comment: Credentials are usually the username, stored in/etc/passwd, and the public ssh key, stored in ~username/.ssh/authorized_keys. To make suggestions, I need to know more. How did you login in the first cloud? What happens when you try to login on the second cloud? Do you have network connectivity to the instance? Did you detect errors in the console log?

Comment: @berndbausch -> There was no problem in logging into the cloud deployment itself. I'm the admin. Everything is done through the command line. There was no error. It comes into the login screen. And when the original snapshot username and password were typed, it shows incorrect username or password. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Can you explain what is "it"? How can the command line have a login screen? If the instance runs Ubuntu, username is stored in /etc/passwd, and the password in /etc/shadow. You could create a volume from the snapshot and attach it to another instance, then compare credentials with the original. Or modify the password on the volume and launch another instance from the modified volume.

Comment: @berndbausch hey, I updated the question for more clarity. Please help thanks.

Comment: As I said, credentials are stored in /etc/password and /etc/shadow. I can't tell what changed those files, but you can create a copy of the image in the second cloud and check for yourself if the file content differs from the original Ubuntu instance. You can even change the password, then boot from that copy.